# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator', table 'AspNetUsers' after modifying ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I have modified my ApplicationUser to include several fields needed for my application. I also set the context that stores the other objects in the Entity Framework to use IdentityDbContext as well so they could share the same database. Everything is going fine, however when I go to create a user an exception is thrown:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator', table 'AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Here is my IdentityModels:

```
Public Class ApplicationUser
    Inherits IdentityUser

    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property OfficePhone As String
    Public Property MobilePhone As String
    Public Property Administrator As Boolean
    Public Property Notifications As Boolean
```

My ApplicationDbContext :

```
    Public Class ApplicationDbContext
        Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of ApplicationUser)

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("ExpressConnection", throwIfV1Schema:=False)
        End Sub

        Public Shared Function Create() As ApplicationDbContext
            Return New ApplicationDbContext()
        End Function

    End Class
```

Here is my context:

```
Public Class MyContext
    Inherits IdentityDbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("DefaultConnection")
    End Sub

    Public Property Clients As DbSet(Of Client)

    Public Property Employees As DbSet(Of ApplicationUser)

    Public Property Invoices As DbSet(Of Invoice)

End Class
```

Here is the code to create a new user:

Create a UserManager object based on the UserStore object and the ApplicationDbContext object.

```
Dim userMgr As New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(context))
Dim appUser As New ApplicationUser

appUser.UserName = "user@example.com"
appUser.Email = "user@example.com"

IdUserResult = userMgr.Create(appUser, "$password$")
```

The database is dropped every time the application starts so the initial migration should handle the changes to ApplicationUser. I'm not sure why when I go to create a new user the application fails with the above exception.

Comment: Show us the code that throw the exception ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound The code is IdUserResult = userMgr.Create(appUser, "$password$"). It has been added to the question.

Comment: I really think the problem exist because you're using the wrong DbContext.

Comment: MAke sure that the instance of the context you pass through UserStore constructor is type of ApplicationDbContext and not in MyContext type. If you use the correct type all should be fine.

Comment: @CodeNotFound The instance of the context that is passed through the UserStore constructor has always been of the type ApplicationDbContext and not the MyContext type.

Comment: If you check your question, you will see that it exists two contexts. That is why I'm telling if you're using the good context. Why do you have two contexts ?

Comment: Thanks @CodeNotFound. I removed the dbContext and put everything into the IdentityDbContext and the Discriminator field disappeared. I was initially using 2 contexts because the Identity information was added later. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool. You're welcome. Happy to know that it works :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound Can a clear answer be posted for other visitors?